# How to get current date and time of server in device

Tags: android, angularjs

I need to show the current date and time in the android device. Codes like Calendar.getInstance() or new Date() return device time.But if device time was not correct, incorrect date will be displayed.

Comment: If you want to know some information from the server on the client, then you have to send it from the server to the client.

Comment: good answer Erwin - pass the server time back to the client in an HTTP header in the response

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use something like SNTP (Simple Network Time Protocol) to connect to a trusted Internet time server.

The problem comes if the user has also changed the time zone to an incorrect one.

The reason why this is a problem in your case is NTP and SNTP retrieve time in UTC format which is good in one way but obviously won't get you the 'local' time based on the devices geographical location. At this point you need to be looking at geo-location services to attempt to identify the location and time zone in order to get an accurate local date / time.

In short, there's no easy one-step answer to this and ultimately it comes down to WHY you need to do this. If a user wishes to mess about with their date / time / time zone settings on their own device then that's their choice.

Comment: here an API for a time server - http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now also see http://www.timeapi.org/